Why can't I install nodegit?
I have been trying for three days to install nodegit as a project dependency, but it just will not build.
The install commands runs, I see it cycle through bash, Python, clang, cmake, and a couple others, so I know it's doing the node-gyp thing.
I think I can say node-gyp is generally functional, because I have another project where I use it to rebuild better-sqlite3 to match the NodeJS ABI of Electron. But it cannot build nodegit.
My versions:
node v20.11.0
npm 10.2.4
node-gyp v10.0.1
Python 3.11.8
OS MacOS 14.4.1 (23E224) ("Sonoma", Apple M2 silicon)
XCode Command Line Tools 15.3.0.0.1.1708646388
Here's what happens when I run npm install nodegit in a completely empty directory:
$ npm install nodegit
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node lifecycleScripts/preinstall && node lifecycleScripts/install
npm ERR! [nodegit] Running pre-install script
npm ERR! [nodegit] Running install script
npm ERR!
npm ERR! SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/acquireOpenSSL.node
npm ERR! ACTION binding_gyp_configureLibssh2_target_configure .
npm ERR! [nodegit] Configuring libssh2.
npm ERR! SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/configureLibssh2.node

Then I get 2200 lines of C++ errors like this one:
npm ERR! /Users/Tom/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-maybe.h:123
npm ERR! :67: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
npm ERR! template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>>* = nullptr>
npm ERR!                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/async_baton.cc:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/../include/async_baton.h:5:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:62:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/Tom/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/node.h:73:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/Tom/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8.h:33:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/Tom/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-function.h:11:
npm ERR! /Users/Tom/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-function-callback.h:151:66: warning: 'static_assert' with no message is a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]
npm ERR!                 kReturnValueDefaultValueIndex - kReturnValueIndex);
npm ERR!                                                                  ^
npm ERR!                                                                  , ""
npm ERR! /Users/Tom/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-function-callback.h:153:50: warning: 'static_assert' with no message is a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]
npm ERR!                 kIsolateIndex - kReturnValueIndex);
npm ERR!                                                  ^
npm ERR!                                                  , ""
npm ERR! 22 warnings and 10 errors generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/nodegit/src/async_baton.o] Error 1

And then it ends like this:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/Tom/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:209:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/Tom/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/Tom/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node" "--module_name=nodegit" "--module_path=/Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v115"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR!
npm ERR! stack
npm ERR! Error: Failed to execute '/Users/Tom/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node /Users/Tom/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node --module_name=nodegit --module_path=/Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v115' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! stack
npm ERR! at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR! System Darwin 23.4.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/Tom/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR!
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Tom/projects/nodegit-testing/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v
npm ERR! v0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - Could not finish install
npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - finished with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/Tom/.npm/_logs/2024-04-05T00_18_01_701Z-debug-0.log

Their website has a broken link to a Slack community.
How do I get past this? Does nodegit work for anybody?
